# Should I use either or any in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, some-any, any-every

So, I want to ask the students to contact me if they are interested in topics A and B. Which one is better?

Please contact me if you are interested in any of the following topics: ...
or
Please contact me if you are interested in either of the following topics: ...

Or, do you think there is a better way to put that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Favour *either* when there are two alternatives, and only one can be taken.

*Either* can allow for more than two alternatives and it can allow that both alternatives can be taken, but there's no point using it in these cases unless you've a good reason; being able to argue you were technically correct is not the point of the exercise.

I don't see why you don't just use:

> Please contact me if you are interested in [A] or [B].

Seems a simpler approach.

Comment: Well, because A and B are long sentences. Just used A and B here to simplify the question.

Comment: I might suggest then; "Please let me know if you are interested in [A], or if you are interested in [B]".